# app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})) throws error on submit

Tags: node.js, express, urlencode, body-parser

I had to submit a form containing few parameters from `localhost:2000/articles/new`.  I put the form method and action as `<form action="/articles" method="POST">`.

My post function is in `article` route and is like this:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("sent")
    console.log(req)
    res.end()
})
```

My `server.js` file contains `app.use("/articles", articleRouter)`

I have used `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))` in server.js file

**Now problem arises here:**

==> when I use the `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))` I get error on submitting form.
The error I got is below:

```
C:\blog\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\dbcs-codec.js:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\blog\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.getCodec (C:\blog\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:65:27)
    at Object.getDecoder (C:\blog\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
```

==>But when I don't use it and submit the form the `console.log` of post function (`router.post` function ) works. I do not know what is the problem here please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED FOR ME**

I simply deleted node modules folder and again ran `npm i` on cmd.

This reinstalled all my node modules and its file, now it is working for me.